# Can a type know when a mutable borrow to itself has ended?

Tags: rust

I have a struct and I want to call one of the struct's methods every time a mutable borrow to it has ended. To do so, I would need to know when the mutable borrow to it has been dropped. How can this be done?

Comment: Interesting, what would you like it to do? I can't envision a reason for needing this

Comment: Can you elaborate on "has been returned"? I think maybe you mean "has ended", in which case you may want to look at how `RefCell` works. But if you mean "has been returned (from any function)", that's not possible.

Comment: @Alexander I was thinking about a use case where every time my struct gets mutated, I want to make sure after I get it back that it still maintains certain invariants. Otherwise, I can label it "corrupted" or something. Does that make sense?

Comment: @trentcl I think I mean "when it has finished mutating" --- I have a struct, I give a mutable reference of it to a function, and the function then does some stuff to the struct, and eventually "ends the mutable borrow" ("returns it?"); as soon as it ends the borrow, I want to call functions that would check to make sure that certain conditions, that all instances of that struct must maintain, are not violated after mutation.

Comment: @user89 Enforce those invariants through the functions of the struct. Don't allow illegal states to happen, hoping you'll detect them after.

Comment: @Alexander makes sense; I was mostly wondering if it was possible.

Comment: @user89 Have a look at the implementation of [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut). When you borrow it mutably it returns a struct `RefMut` that wraps the reference. `RefMut` implements `Drop` so it can perform an action when the reference goes out of scope. To me that sounds exactly like what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** The answer that follows describes a possible solution, but it's not a very good one, as described by this comment from Sebastien Redl:

> [T]his is a *bad* way of trying to maintain invariants. Mostly because dropping the reference can be suppressed with `mem::forget`. This is fine for `RefCell`, where if you don't drop the ref, you will simply eventually panic because you didn't release the dynamic borrow, but it is bad if violating the "fraction is in shortest form" invariant leads to weird results or subtle performance issues down the line, and it is catastrophic if you need to maintain the "thread doesn't outlive variables in the current scope" invariant.

Nevertheless, it's possible to use a temporary struct as a "staging area" that updates the referent when it's dropped, and thus maintain the invariant correctly; however, that version basically amounts to making a proper wrapper type and a kind of weird way to use it. The best way to solve this problem is through an opaque wrapper struct that doesn't expose its internals except through methods that definitely maintain the invariant.

Without further ado, the original answer:

---

Not *exactly*... but pretty close. We can use `RefCell<T>` as a model for how this can be done. It's a bit of an abstract question, but I'll use a concrete example to demonstrate. (This won't be a *complete* example, but something to show the general principles.)

Let's say you want to make a `Fraction` struct that is always in simplest form (fully reduced, e.g. 3/5 instead of 6/10).  You write a struct `RawFraction` that will contain the bare data. `RawFraction` instances are *not* always in simplest form, but they have a method `fn reduce(&mut self)` that reduces them.

Now you need a smart pointer type that you will always use to mutate the `RawFraction`, which calls `.reduce()` on the pointed-to struct when it's dropped. Let's call it `RefMut`, because that's the naming scheme `RefCell` uses. You implement `Deref<Target = RawFraction>`, `DerefMut`, and `Drop` on it, something like this:

```
pub struct RefMut<'a>(&'a mut RawFraction);

impl<'a> Deref for RefMut<'a> {
    type Target = RawFraction;
    fn deref(&self) -> &RawFraction {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> DerefMut for RefMut<'a> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut RawFraction {
        self.0
    }
}

impl<'a> Drop for RefMut<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.0.reduce();
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you have a `RefMut` to a `RawFraction` and drop it, you know the `RawFraction` will be in simplest form afterwards. All you need to do at this point is ensure that `RefMut` is the *only* way to get `&mut` access to the `RawFraction` part of a `Fraction`.

```
pub struct Fraction(RawFraction);

impl Fraction {
    pub fn new(numerator: i32, denominator: i32) -> Self {
        // create a RawFraction, reduce it and wrap it up
    }

    pub fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> RefMut {
        RefMut(&mut self.0)
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the `pub` markings (and lack thereof): I'm using those to ensure the soundness of the exposed interface. All three types should be placed in a module by themselves. It would be incorrect to mark the `RawFraction` field `pub` inside `Fraction`, since then it would be possible (for code outside the module) to create an unreduced `Fraction` without using `new` or get a `&mut RawFraction` without going through `RefMut`.

Supposing all this code is placed in a module named `frac`, you can use it something like this (assuming `Fraction` implements `Display`):

```
let f = frac::Fraction::new(3, 10);
println!("{}", f); // prints 3/10
f.borrow_mut().numerator += 3;
println!("{}", f); // prints 3/5
```

The types encode the invariant: Wherever you have `Fraction`, you can know that it's fully reduced. When you have a `RawFraction`, `&RawFraction`, etc., you can't be sure. If you want, you may also make `RawFraction`'s fields non-`pub`, so that you can't get an unreduced fraction *at all* except by calling `borrow_mut` on a `Fraction`.

Comment: Note, however, that this is a *bad* way of trying to maintain invariants. Mostly because dropping the reference can be suppressed with `mem::forget`. This is fine for `RefCell`, where if you don't drop the ref, you will simply eventually panic because you didn't release the dynamic borrow, but it is bad if violating the "fraction is in shortest form" invariant leads to weird results or subtle performance issues down the line, and it is catastrophic if you need to maintain the "thread doesn't outlive variables in the current scope" invariant.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Ah, that's true. :( I tried to come up with a way that `drop` not being called would be a problem, but I was going for subtle, possibly accidental ways and I didn't think about just passing it to `mem::forget`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same thing is done in [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut). There you want to reduce the runtime borrow-count when a borrow ends. Here you want to perform an arbitrary action.

So let's re-use the concept of writing a function that returns a wrapped reference:

```
struct Data {
    content: i32,
}

impl Data {
    fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> DataRef {
        println!("borrowing");
        DataRef { data: self }
    }

    fn check_after_borrow(&self) {
        if self.content > 50 {
            println!("Hey, content should be <= {:?}!", 50); 
        }
    }
}

struct DataRef<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Data
}

impl<'a> Drop for DataRef<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("borrow ends");
        self.data.check_after_borrow()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut d = Data { content: 42 };    
    println!("content is {}", d.content);    
    {
        let b = d.borrow_mut();
        //let c = &d;  // Compiler won't let you have another borrow at the same time
        b.data.content = 123;
        println!("content set to {}", b.data.content);
    }  // borrow ends here
    println!("content is now {}", d.content);
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
content is 42
borrowing
content set to 123
borrow ends
Hey, content should be <= 50!
content is now 123
```

Be aware that you can still obtain an unchecked mutable borrow with e.g. `let c = &mut d;`. This will be silently dropped without calling `check_after_borrow`.

Comment: Beat me by a hair! ;)

Comment: @trentcl Maybe because you spent more time on explaining :)